# Aggregation in UPDATE SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregation

So, I have currently have two tables, one containing the fixed part of each object, and the other containing a variable number of properties of each object as key/value pairs. I would like to convert these properties to a CLOB field in the main table in JSON map format.

```sql
create table test_a (id integer, properties clob);
create table test_b (id integer, a_id integer, key char(30), value char(30));

insert into test_a values(1,'');
insert into test_a values(2,'');
insert into test_a values(3,'');

insert into test_b values (1, 1, 'k1', 'v1');
insert into test_b values (2, 1, 'k2', 'v2');
insert into test_b values (3, 2, 'k3', 'v3');
insert into test_b values (4, 2, 'k4', 'v4');
insert into test_b values (5, 2, 'k5', 'v5');
insert into test_b values (6, 2, 'k6', 'v6');
```

I can build the JSON I want via the following query:

```
WITH PROPS AS
  (SELECT '"'
    ||trim(KEY)
    ||'":"'
    ||trim(value)
    ||'"' json,
    test_b.*
  FROM test_b
  )
SELECT test_a.id,
  '{'
  ||
  (SELECT listagg(json, ',') within GROUP (
  ORDER BY props.key)
  FROM PROPS
  WHERE PROPS.A_ID = test_a.id
  )
  || '}'
FROM TEST_A
INNER JOIN PROPS
ON TEST_A.ID = PROPS.A_ID
GROUP BY TEST_A.ID ;
```

And I get the desired result

```
1   "{""k1"":""v1"",""k2"":""v2""}"
2   "{""k3"":""v3"",""k4"":""v4"",""k5"":""v5"",""k6"":""v6""}"
```

But when I try to use this result to insert into the master table, I get errors

```
UPDATE TEST_A SET PROPERTIES = (
WITH PROPS AS
  (SELECT '"'
    ||trim(key)
    ||'":"'
    ||trim(value)
    ||'"' json,
    test_b.*
  FROM test_b
  )
SELECT '{'
  ||
  (SELECT listagg(json, ',') within GROUP (order by props.key) FROM PROPS
  WHERE PROPS.A_ID = test_a.id)
  || '}'  from TEST_A INNER JOIN PROPS ON TEST_A.ID = PROPS.A_ID GROUP BY TEST_A.ID
) ;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery rather than a `group by`.  The entire outer query doesn't look right, so I think you need something like:

```
UPDATE TEST_A
    SET PROPERTIES = (
        WITH PROPS AS (
              SELECT '"'||trim(key)||'":"'||trim(value)||'"' as json,
                     test_b.*
              FROM test_b
             )
        SELECT '{' || listagg(json, ',') within GROUP (order by props.key) || '}'
        FROM PROPS
        WHERE PROPS.A_ID = test_a.id
       ) ;
```